# Highslide not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, highslide

I installed Highslide in my website but it seems like it's not working.

I saved the Highslide folders into my website main folder and put this in the head of my HTML document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/highslide/highslide.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/highslide/highslide.css"/> <script type="text/javascript">
// override Highslide settings here
// instead of editing the highslide.js file
hs.graphicsDir = '/highslide/graphics/'; </script>
```

But when i try to use the image zoom pop up code it doesn't work:

```
<a class="highslide" href="images/thumbstrip13.jpg" onclick="return
hs.expand(this)">    <img src="images/thumbstrip13.thumb.png" alt=""/>
</a>
```

The image doesn't pop up like it should but it simply open in another window. Where did I do wrong?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: The paths to the highslide.js and highslide.css files are probably wrong. Ditto for the hs.graphicsDir path. Those are pointing to the root of your hosting account, which is not necessarily the same as the root of your web site. But without being able to see your page, I'm just guessing.